# Socket class Error

Tags: c++

ListenSocket.h

```
    //  class does not contain WSASTARTUP () and WSACLEANUP ()

#ifndef LISTENTHREAD_H
#define LISTENTHREAD_H
#include "includes.h"
#include "LOGMSGs.h"

// 1, CListenSocket: class is used to create the listener thread local variable.
// This class can be reused. When you call Close () is closed, re-calling Open () the new listening port. But the system did not use the feature.
class   CListenSocket
{
public:
    // main method:
    // BIND each object only to a port.
    CListenSocket(u_short nPort, int nSndSize = 0);
    // to release SOCKET
    ~CListenSocket(){};
    // Create server listening SOCKET, specific options see the code. Fails to return false.
    bool    Open();     // call can be repeated
    // error return INVALID_SOCKET
    SOCKET  Accept(u_long & nClientIP);
    // repeated calls. Usually not, can be used to take the initiative to close the SOCKET.
    // close the re-call after Open () re-use the object.
    void    Close();        // call can be repeated
    bool    IsOpen() { return m_bState; }
    bool    Rebuild();
public:
    SOCKET  Socket() { return m_sockListen; }
protected:
    // main member variables:
    const u_short   m_nPort;
    const int       m_nSndBuf;
    SOCKET  m_sockListen;
    // network status is normal sign.
    // When the value is false that the object is not available. May not have Open (), may also be a network error.
    bool    m_bState;
    time_t  m_tCloseTime;       // SOCKET last closed the time delay for the automatic re-SOCKET
};



#endif  // LISTENTHREAD_H
```

ListenSocket.cpp

```
#include "ListenSocket.h"
long    s_nSocketCount = 0;
int     REBUILDLISTENDELAYSEC;

CListenSocket::CListenSocket(u_short nPort, int nSndBuf /*= 0*/)    // 0: Default
         : m_nPort(nPort), m_nSndBuf(nSndBuf)
{
    m_sockListen    = INVALID_SOCKET;
    m_bState        = false;
//  m_nPort         = nPort;
    m_tCloseTime    = 0;
}

//  Error returned INVALID_SOCKET
SOCKET  CListenSocket::Accept(u_long & nClientIP)
{
/*
    // Reconstruction SOCKET
    if(!m_bState)
    {
        if(clock() < m_tCloseTime + REBUILDLISTENDELAYSEC*CLOCKS_PER_SEC)
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        else
        {
            LOGMSG("Anti-crash system start listening SOCKET [%d] re under construction...", m_nPort);
            if(Open())
            {
                LOGMSG("... listen SOCKET reconstruction success.");
                PrintText("Listen SOCKET [%d] failed to rebuild SOCKET success. Server continues to run in the ...", m_nPort);
            }
            else
            {
                Error("... listen SOCKET reconstruction has failed. Server will not accept new connections");
                PrintText("Listen SOCKET [%d] error, [%d] seconds after the re-SOCKET. Server continues to run in the ...", m_nPort, REBUILDLISTENDELAYSEC);        // nDelaySec);
            }
            m_tCloseTime = clock();
        }
    }
//*/
    if(!m_bState)
    {
        Error("ACCEPT inner exception a1");
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    // ACCEPT
    struct sockaddr_in  addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    int    len = sizeof(addr);
    SOCKET newsock = accept(m_sockListen, (sockaddr*)&addr, (int*)&len);        // receive to the other side of the map, you can use
#ifdef  PROFILE_X
            // Analysis Accept speed (cycle speed)
            const int   nTimes2 = ACCEPTPROFILESEC;     // Statistics once every 30 seconds the speed ACCEPT
            static  clock_t tNextTime2 = clock() + nTimes2 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;    //? Only one monitor thread, no sharing violation
            static long nCount2 = 0;                                //? Only one monitor thread, no sharing violation
            if(clock() >= tNextTime2)
            {
                PrintText("Each [%d] seconds to execute a [%d] times Accept ()", nTimes2, InterlockedExchange(&nCount2, 0));
                tNextTime2 = clock() + nTimes2 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            }
            else
            {
                InterlockedIncrement(&nCount2);
            }
#endif  // PROFILE
    if(newsock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        // Network Error
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        if(err != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            PrintText("Listen SOCKET %d failed, %s seconds after the re-SOCKET.", m_nPort, REBUILDLISTENDELAYSEC);
            Error("Listen SOCKET [%d] failed [%d], [%s] seconds after the re-SOCKET.", m_nPort, err, REBUILDLISTENDELAYSEC);
            Close();
        }
        else
            Error("ACCEPT inner exception a2");
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    else
    {
        nClientIP = addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr;
        InterlockedIncrement(&s_nSocketCount);
    }

    // Check whether the SOCKET closed 
    fd_set  readmask;
    FD_ZERO(&readmask);
    FD_SET(newsock, &readmask);
    struct timeval  timeout = {0, 0};
/*
    char nTemp;
    if(select(FD_SETSIZE, &readmask, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) 0, &timeout) 
            && recv(newsock, &nTemp, 1, MSG_PEEK) == 0)
    {
#ifdef  ALPHA_X
        LOGMSG("ACCEPT a new SOCKET is invalid .");
#endif
        closesocket(newsock);
        InterlockedDecrement(&s_nSocketCount);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
//else*/
//*
    fd_set  exceptmask;
    FD_ZERO(&exceptmask);
    FD_SET(newsock, &exceptmask);
    int ret = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readmask, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) &exceptmask, &timeout);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        Error("ACCEPT a new SOCKET is invalid . can't read");       // Not trigger
        closesocket(newsock);
        InterlockedDecrement(&s_nSocketCount);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    else if(ret > 0)
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(newsock, &exceptmask))
        {
            LOGMSG("ACCEPT a new SOCKET is invalid.except");        // Not trigger
            closesocket(newsock);
            InterlockedDecrement(&s_nSocketCount);
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
        else if(FD_ISSET(newsock, &readmask))
        {
            char nTemp;
            if(recv(newsock, &nTemp, 1, MSG_PEEK) == 0)
            {
#ifdef  ALPHA_X
                LOGMSG("ACCEPT a new SOCKET is invalid. recv==0");      // Not trigger
#endif
                closesocket(newsock);
                InterlockedDecrement(&s_nSocketCount);
                return INVALID_SOCKET;
            }
        }
    }
//*/
#ifdef  PROFILE_X
            // analysis Accept speed (received valid SOCKET)
            const int   nTimes = ACCEPTPROFILESEC;      // Statistics once every 10 seconds the speed ACCEPT
            static  clock_t tNextTime = clock() + nTimes * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;      //? Only one monitor thread, no sharing violation
            static long nCount  = 0;                            //? Only one monitor thread, no sharing violation
            if(clock() >= tNextTime)
            {
                LOGPROFILE("Port [%d] for every [%d] seconds, the successful implementation of the [%d] times Accept()", 
                            m_nPort, nTimes, InterlockedExchange(&nCount, 0));
                tNextTime = clock() + nTimes * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            }
            else
            {
                InterlockedIncrement(&nCount);
            }
#endif  // PROFILE

    return newsock;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "includes.h"
#include "IniFile.h"
#include "LOGMSGs.h"
#include "ListenSocket.h"

CListenSocket Sock(9985);
int main()
{
    Sock.Open();
    if(!Sock.Open())
    {
        Sock.Rebuild();
    }
    if(Sock.IsOpen())
        PrintText("okey");
    Sock.Socket();
    u_long ip;
    Sock.Accept(ip);
}
```

but i always got this error : ACCEPT inner exception a2 while it should work anyclue why?

Comment: at what part of your code does it error

Comment: Is this homework? If not, don't reinvent the wheel. Use a proven networking library like [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html).

Comment: @Marlon  when if(newsock == INVALID_SOCKET)

Comment: @Sam Miller am coding something for a game so i should work this way :S

Comment: games can (and do) use Boost.

Answer (score 0):

```
CListenSocket Sock(9985);
int main()
{
    Sock.Open();
    if(!Sock.Open())

/* I think you meant 'IsOpen()' */

    {
        Sock.Rebuild();
    }
    if(Sock.IsOpen())
        PrintText("okey");
    Sock.Socket();
    u_long ip;
    Sock.Accept(ip);
}
```

Incidentally, this code sure *reads* funny. It feels like a generic toolkit programmed without a specific goal in mind. Maybe I'm missing it, but I have to think you'd have better results if you just wrote the network code that actually *needed*, and then abstract out the common bits into some helper routines later. There's no point in trying too hard to make the be-all and end-all network helper library, but there is a huge point in making tools that collapse common cases.

Feel free to ignore that last paragraph if you know what you're doing :) but if you're just starting out, I'd like to suggest writing a few smaller clients and servers, and *then* try writing your abstraction layer.

Comment: well Sock.Open or IsOpen  wont make diffrent here the error happend when it's try to make new socket so it's sending an invalid socket thats why! idk why it's sending an invalid sock while i made it before but with out a class :S